# Interpretation of Pangenome: high number of accessory genes

Tags: bacteriology, genomics

I performed a pangenomic analysis on a collection of 52 strains belonging to the same genus (some 5-6 different species). All the strains were isolated from the same environment: interior compartment of surface-sterilized plant root.

Now, the results of my analysis (I used the R package FindMyFriends) indicated a total of 32911 gene groups divided as follow:

- 581 core (present in 95% or more of the genomes)
- 6116 shell (present in 15 to 95% of the genomes)
- 26214 cloud (present in up to 15% of the genomes)

This results are quite unexpected. Even though it is typical that most gene groups get labeled as cloud or accessory, it surprises me that the percentage is so high! Especially given the common origin of those strains.

Other software I tried (Roary, BPGA, microPAN) gave similar or more extreme results, so I can exclude a technical error.

Therefore, if anyone has some experience with pangenomic data, some input on how to interpret this data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know this area, but have you considered the possible presence of other organisms' DNA from contamination or the presence of eukaryotic (e.g. fungal) or prokaryotic cells inside the root tissue sample?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I did an [edit] that I think improves the readability of your question (e.g.s: your use of "begets" didn't make sense to me, and "worst" means most negative, which feels ... unnecessarily subjective) . Feel free to make more changes if you feel I've altered your meaning.  ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: @Rob, I'm unfamiliar with BGPA and microPAN, but I've used Roary and [PanPhlAn](http://segatalab.cibio.unitn.it/tools/panphlan/). Some questions so that I can better understand your system: What is the average size (+deviation) of these 52 genomes?  Are these draft or finished genomes?  If draft genomes, how fragmented are they (how many scaffolds, on average)?

Comment: @mgkrebbs I would exclude that as the process of binning during the assembly should have taken care of that

Comment: @Dirigible The average size is 5.7 MB with SD of 1.2. I did not process them myself, but they are drafts, with an average of 76 scaffolds. However one of the genomes is almost double in size compared to the others and I believe I should probably discard it.